Using turnstile with nuxt on netlify
I'm trying to use turnstile with nuxt on netlify.
When using turnstile in server/api (nuxt) on local host it works.
validateTurnstile.js for server/api looks like this
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const body = await readBody(event)
    return await verifyTurnstileToken(body.token || body['cf-turnstile-response'])
  })

and in signup.vue page we validate token like this
  async validateToken() {
    let response; 
    try {
      response = await $fetch('api/validateTurnstile', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          token: this.token,
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Token validation error:", error);
      return false;
    }
    return response;
  },

But for this to work I have to use edge-functions in netlify?
I tried setting up according to docs. When writting file to netlify/edge-functions/validateTurnstile.js I get error that function is not found
validateTurnstile.js for edge-functions should look like this?
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const { token } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    // Your logic here, for example:
    const result = await verifyTurnstileToken(token);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }),
    };
  }
};

** EDIT **
When using netlify edge function (instead of server/api ) I would need to change validateToken (from signup.vue) fetch location to await $fetch('/validateTurnstile'... so it would fetch token data.
I tried accessing url localhost:8888/validateTurnstile to see what's there but I get this error

{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Could not find function
'validateTurnstile'","trace":["Error: Could not find function
'validateTurnstile'\n    at FunctionChain.getFunction
(https://v2-8-1--edge.netlify.com/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:248:13)\n
at FunctionChain.runFunction
(https://v2-8-1--edge.netlify.com/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:353:23)\n
at FunctionChain.run
(https://v2-8-1--edge.netlify.com/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:323:31)\n
at handleRequest
(https://v2-8-1--edge.netlify.com/bootstrap/handler.ts:148:34)\n    at
https://v2-8-1--edge.netlify.com/bootstrap/server.ts:39:7\n    at
ext:deno_http/00_serve.ts:364:24\n    at
ext:deno_http/00_serve.ts:552:29\n    at eventLoopTick
(ext:core/01_core.js:168:7)"]}

In the developer console I get this message

signup.vue:279 Token validation error: FetchError: [POST]
"/validateTurnstile": 404 Not Found
at async $fetch22 (ofetch.00501375.mjs:261:15)
at async Proxy.validateToken (signup.vue:272:1)
at async Proxy.handleSubmit (signup.vue:289:1)

my file structure of root looks like this:


Which function is not found? Does it work if you build and preview locally? api/validateTurnstile looks like a weird endpoint. Don't you need a / in front of it? Some details regarding your file structure + endpoints created would be welcome. Then, check your network to find out what does not work exactly.

Updated text. Doesn't work neither on localhost (I have installed netlify-cli and use netlify dev to run) and on netlify itself

If I am not mistaken, you need to name your Netlify function with the name of the endpoint (or at least configure the path in the file) you are trying to reach. Here it looks like it is not exposed under the /validateTurnstile endpoint. Also, a file structure by text is quite hard to read. Please consider sharing a screenshot of your file tree rather. But the issue is probably because of the naming of the function.

I am not sure about your use-case but one of my functions looks like this
/netlify/edge-functions/context.ts
import type { Config, Context } from "@netlify/edge-functions";

export const config: Config = {
  path: "/netlify-edge",
};

export default async (request: Request, context: Context) => {
  console.log('Netlify context', context)

  return Response.json({
    context
  });
};

Try to add a similar path to yours too.
